# Checking a range of cells against user input VBA

Tags: excel, user-input, vba

I am trying to check a small range of values against a value input by the user. The query loops through the range, but it never hits line ActiveCell.EntireRow.Clear when it should. My code is below, any ideas?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim myValue2 As String
myValue2 = InputBox("Enter Last Name:")

With ActiveSheet

    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 33 To iLastRow
        If ActiveCell.Value = myValue2 Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Clear

    Else

    End If
        Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need ActiveCell:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myValue2 As String
    myValue2 = InputBox("Enter Last Name:")
    With ActiveSheet
        iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 33 To iLastRow
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = myValue2 Then
                Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Clear
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```